# Force Visual Studio to build solutions synchronously

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

Visual Studio seems to have changed behaviour recently, somewhere between versions 17.5.5 and 17.7.0. I am wondering if there is a way to restore the old behaviour, since the new behaviour is causing problems with our build process.

We have some solutions containing installer projects (`.vdproj`). Since MSBuild can't build these, we have an extra build step that calls Visual Studio, as follows:

```
devenv.com $SolutionFileName /build $BuildConfiguration /out $LogFile
```

This used to build the solution and wait until it had finished before ending the process. Now it spins off another process to do the build and exits immediately. I can see this happening because:

- The script runs through all the solutions very quickly without stopping, despite waiting for `devenv.com` to exit.
- Build status details used to be written to standard output, but now nothing is written.
- The log files all start at 0 bytes, and gradually fill with content asynchronously.

There is no mention of this new behaviour in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2022), or any command line switches to control the behaviour.

##### Implementation Details

`devenv.com` is run like this in Powershell, which waits for the `devenv.com` process to finish, but not for any child processes that it spawns.

```
$Process = Start-Process -FilePath $FilePath -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -NoNewWindow -PassThru
if($Process) {
    $Handle = $Process.Handle
    if($Process.WaitForExit([int]::MaxValue)) {
        return $Process.ExitCode
    }
}
return -1
```

If I add `-Wait` to `Start-Process`, then it correctly waits for child processes of `devenv.com`, but still displays nothing on standard output.